# Design ER with complicated relationships between different tables

Tags: database-design

I try to design a database and I am stuck dealing with a part of it. The problem is very scientific, so for simplicity, I will try to give you a simple representation that accurately matches the case.

Imagine we have an oven with many drawer **tray**s (each can only be used once and then get stored), and each tray is split in a specific number of **compartment**s. That is either:

- 8 compartments
- 2 compartments
- no compartments (or 1 big if you like)

You can call it 3 types of trays if that's better for the database design, in case some other type becomes available in the future.

Now, we have **project**s (imagine persons) and each project can have 1 or more **iteration**s (imagine bakes). Each iteration can have 1 or more **sample**s (imagine cakes). Each iteration is assigned to 1 **tray**. Two or more iterations of *different* projects that run at the same time, can be assigned at the same tray. However, two iterations of the *same* project *CANNOT* be assigned at the same tray. Imagine a new iteration will come at a later date, so since the trays are single-use, the next iteration has to be assigned on a new tray.

Each sample can be stored in 1 or more **compartment**s (we can divide a cake in smaller cakes and bake them in several compartments of the same tray). Also, 1 compartment can hold 1 or more **sample**s from the same iteration of the same project (imagine we divide the cake to 4 parts, and we bake 2 parts in compartment_1 and 2 in compartment_2), or from an iteration of a different **project**.

---

So in other words, two or more projects can run in parallel, and their iterations can be assigned to one tray. Future iterations of either of the projects will be assigned in a different tray. Each sample and compartment can be related in any order, and we need to keep track of everything.

I have tried several things, but nothing feels good enough to post here as ER. My tables are the ones I have in **bold**: project, tray, sample, iteration, (not sure about compartment).

Since a `project` can use many trays, and a `tray` can host many projects, I use the `iteration` table as a join table. But now I have no clue where I should connect the `sample`.

- A `tray` is hosting many samples, while 1 sample only uses 1 tray, so I could connect them 1-to-many. However, I also need to keep track of whether the sample is stored in 1 compartment or spread out on more. Then I also need to know which project each sample belongs to.
- Similarly, if I relate sample to project, I will not have information about the tray relation to the sample.
- An `iteration` may have 1 or more samples, while 1 sample can be in 1 iteration, so I could create a relationship sample-iteration. This way I will be able to know both the project and the tray each sample is related to. However, the compartment problem remains.

Sounds like a chasm trap, so a triangle relationship could be the way to go, but I am not experienced enough and I'm not sure how to design something like this.

To tackle the compartment problem, I could use a field in `sample` to store the compartment information and use the software to make sure the compartment values are as supposed to be. But not sure this is the right choice.

Any help to design an ER for this part of the project is highly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Can samples from a given project iteration be on more than one tray in the oven when baked?
2. Is it possible to have two project iterations of the same project in the oven at the same time, but on different trays?

Comment: 1. Yes, a project can have many samples. In each iteration, a few of them are grouped together in a tray. 2. Yes, the iterations of a project are given an increasing integer ID (and they are in separate trays), so they can be in the oven at the same time or in succession. 

Also, you may want to keep in mind that in the future I will have to develop different tables for samples with different needs. Say, bread, lasagna, etc. So the architecture should allow a relatively easy extension of the sample-like tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of having **iterations** as a join table for **trays** and **projects** seems good.

**samples** are obviously strongly related to **iterations**, because one **sample** belongs an **iteration**, and an **iteration** contains several **samples**. Therefore I would make an **iterations** 1..n **samples** association.

Then, **compartments** belongs to a **tray**. But we can also see **compartments** as generic identifiers which, when associated with a **tray**, defines a specific "location" for a **sample**. We already know to which **tray** **samples** of an **iteration** are associated. Also, a **compartment** can contain several **samples**, and a **sample** can be spread into several **compartments**. So we need a join table between **samples** and **compartments**.
If we keep **compartments** as generic identifier (see them as slot numbers in a **tray**), we don't need relationship between **trays** and **compartments**. When filling a **sample**, we already know to which **tray** it belongs through the **iteration**. The user will just have to fill the **compartment(s)** where the sample is located.

You can also enforce the **compartment** choices for the user by setting a type to the **tray**, which let you know what **compartments** can be choosen.